# How to compile ANY Linux kernel module

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

If I try to compile ath.ko module like this

```
root@debian:~/linux-5.13.19# make M=$(pwd)/drivers/net/wireless/ath modules
```

it works.
But if I try to compile iwlwifi.ko module the same way, it fails

```
root@debian:~/linux-5.13.19# make M=$(pwd)/drivers/net/wireless/intel modules
  CC [M]  /root/linux-5.13.19/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/dvm/main.o
/root/linux-5.13.19/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/dvm/main.c:33:10: fatal error: iwl-eeprom-read.h: No such file or directory
   33 | #include "iwl-eeprom-read.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

root@debian:~/linux-5.13.19# make M=$(pwd)/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi modules
  CC [M]  /root/linux-5.13.19/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/dvm/main.o
/root/linux-5.13.19/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/dvm/main.c:33:10: fatal error: iwl-eeprom-read.h: No such file or directory
   33 | #include "iwl-eeprom-read.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

root@debian:~/linux-5.13.19/drivers/net/wireless/intel# make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD
make: Entering directory '/root/linux-5.13.19'
  CC [M]  /root/linux-5.13.19/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/dvm/main.o
/root/linux-5.13.19/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/dvm/main.c:33:10: fatal error: iwl-eeprom-read.h: No such file or directory
   33 | #include "iwl-eeprom-read.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

This happens only I if try to compile the module alone. If I try to compile all modules, it works, but it takes a long time.

```
root@debian:~/linux-5.13.19# time make -j8 modules
```

What are the rules in compiling any Linux kernel modules?
Why when I compile iwlwifi it doesn't find `/root/linux-5.13.19/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwl-eeprom-read.h`?
I can't find the place in the kernel Makefiles where the variable `M` is used, to understand why it fails.

Comment: Just to note, an argument of `M=foo` doesn't set the make variable `M=`, it sets the make variable `M` so you won't find anywhere in the makefiles where the variable `M=` is used.

Comment: M is for specifying external modules. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19-rc7/source/Makefile#L126

Comment: You can compile any module in Linux, not an issue, just create an appropriate _Makefile_. But for in-tree code it's advised to recompile in with corresponding `make` command line. If you want to speed up the (re-)compilation process, use `ccache`.